# Can anyone teach me SQL for Joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following tables:

```
table 1                             table 2
id   q_id   content                 id  |  w_id  |   q_id  | c_id  | ranking
----------------------          ------------------------------------------------
95   2046   1=E                     123 | 22404  |  2046   |  100  |   1

96   2046   2=G                     124 |  22404 |  2046   |  101  |   2

97   2046   3=N                     125 |  22404 |  2046   |  102  |  2

98   2046   4=B                     126 |  22404 |  2046   |  103  |   2

99   2046   5=V                     127 |  22404 |  2046   |  104  |   3

100  2046   A1                      128 |  22404 |  2046   |  105  |   3

101  2046   A2                      129 |  22405 |  2046   |  100  |   4

102  2046   A3                      130 |  22405 |  2046   |  101  |   4

103  2046   A4                      131 |  22405 |  2046   |  102  |   1

104  2046   A5                      132 |  22405 |  2046   |  103  |   2

105  2046   A6                      133 |  22405 |  2046   |  104  |   2

                                    134 |  22405 |  2046   |  105  |   3
```

I need to write an SQL so that I can get the following result:

```
w_id  | q_id  | A1  | A2  | A3  | A4  | A5  | A6 
--------------------------------------------------- 
22404 | 2046  |  1  |  2  |  2  |  2  |  3  |  3  
22405 | 2046  |  4  |  4  |  1  |  2  |  2  |  3
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you can have an arbitrary number of columns, not just 100-105, then you need a PIVOT. Otherwise this can be done with just a join.

Comment: I'm using mySQL and cannot use pivot can you show me another method?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to join these tables.

You probably need something like this:

```
SELECT w_id as W , q_id, 
(select ranking from table2 where w_id = W and c_id = 100) as 100,
(select ranking from table2 where w_id = W and c_id = 101) as 101,
(select ranking from table2 where w_id = W and c_id = 102) as 102,
(select ranking from table2 where w_id = W and c_id = 103) as 103,
(select ranking from table2 where w_id = W and c_id = 104) as 104,
(select ranking from table2 where w_id = W and c_id = 105) as 105
FROM table2;
```

Comment: thankyou very much ,
I think i need modify sth as shown above
 
 can you also show me the dynamic one?